# I have a simple image picture slider with JQuery, but I do not know how to animate up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: This is I coded by js and jQuery]

I just want the up and down button at the right side of the picture slider work.
Currently, my js code is:

```
 var height_value = 104 * (-1)*3; 
 var top_value=0;
 $("#photoViewerCont .nextPage").click(function(){
    alert("here");
    top_value=top_value+height_value;
    $("#photoViewer .thumbs .pages").animate({'top' : height_value}, 1000,function(){
        $("#photoViewer .thumbs .pages").css({'top' : top_value});

    });
    return false;
 });
```

The HTML part of this js:

```
<div id="photoViewer" class="stackItem">
<div id="photoViewerCont">
<div id="mainPhoto" class="preview">
    <div class="innerCont">
        <a onclick="return false;" rel="photos" data-id="113195895"
            href="#"> <img
            width="456" height="342"
            title="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
            alt="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157" data-index="0"
            src="1.jpg">

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="thumbs">
    <div class="innerCont">
        <div class="paginated">
            <div class="pages" style="height: 634px; top: 0px;">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="thumb" id="defaultpic">
                        <img class="thumb_0" width="120" height="90"
                            data-type="main_photo"
                            title="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            alt="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            src="1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img class="thumb_1" width="120" height="90" data-type="photo"
                            title="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            alt="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            src="2.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img class="thumb_2" width="120" height="90" data-type="photo"
                            title="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            alt="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            src="3.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img class="thumb_3" width="120" height="90" data-type="photo"
                            title="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            alt="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            src="4.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <img class="thumb_4" width="120" height="90" 
                            title="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            alt="112 Cattai Ridge Road, Glenorie, NSW 2157"
                            src="5.jpg">
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="previousPage" href="#">Previous</a> 
    <a class="nextPage" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
<div class="clearer"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

the css part of this file:

```
#photoViewer .thumbs {
-moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
-moz-border-left-colors: none;
-moz-border-right-colors: none;
-moz-border-top-colors: none;
border-color: #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #CCCCCC -moz-use-text-color;
border-image: none;
border-style: solid solid solid none;
border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
float: right;
width: 165px;
}

.thumbs {
position: relative;
}

#photoViewerCont .innerCont {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
height: 346px;
padding: 12px;
}

#photoViewer .thumbs .paginated {
height: 312px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: 18px;
width: 130px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#photoViewerCont a.previousPage {
border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
top: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
text-indent: 5000px;
}
#photoViewerCont a.nextPage {
background-position: -57px 0;
border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
bottom: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
text-indent: 5000px;
}
#photoViewerCont a.previousPage, #photoViewerCont a.nextPage {
background: url("photoviewer_arrows.png") no-repeat scroll -3px 0 #C20014;
border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
display: inline-block;
height: 24px;
right: 61px;
width: 48px;

}

#photoViewerCont a.nextPage {
background-position: -57px 0;
border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
display: inline-block;
height: 24px;
right: 61px;
width: 48px;
 }
```

It can go to the alert part, but the animate part seems doesn't work. Can anyone know where my wrong or can give me a simple example of how picture slide gliding and rising.

Comment: We need to see the CSS and HTML for the entire gallery element. Animating the 'top' property will only work if the pictures on the right are positioned absolutely within their parent container.

Comment: I give you html, but the css part I think is too long and you should know the css just style don't work with function.

Comment: Except without the CSS we have absolutely no idea what CSS properties we'll need to animate to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: put your code in a jsfiddle or better in a http://tinkerbin.com/ to get faster replies (why dont u just get a popular slider/gallery from the jquery plugins repository?)

Comment: The boss want the outer look as the picture above, I try some plugin, but it looks slight different, if you have the some viewed j-query plugin, can you give me the plugin address?

Comment: I put my code to tinkerbin, but How let you can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in this situation, that's what you can do. Wasn't bad at all...

```
margin-top: height
```

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/KtemP/1/)

Comment: thank you, by the way can you tell me the different margin-top and top?

Comment: if you have firebug / chrome (F12) select an element and watch computed values.

hard to explain see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top

Comment: `margin-top` is a forced amount of space between an element and the element above that element (think "pushing away from"), where as `top` is an absolute position of element, without regards to any other element (think "it goes here").