# CSS positioning relative not showing the top margin

Tags: css, css-position, percentage, screen-resolution

My client needs the webpage in middle of the screen. For that , I declared the whole webpage within a div called `mainpage`. CSS:

```
#mainpage
{

    position:relative;
    width:850px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:70%;
    top:15%;
    background:#F1F1F1;

}
```

But the above css does not display at middle of the screen vertically. If I give `absolute` or `fixed` , it is at the middle of the screen vertically, but horizontally it is right aligned ! How can I get the desired result ?

EDIT:
My HTML codes

```
<body>
<div id="mainpage_wrapper">  
<div id="mainpage">

   <div id="header_wrapper">
    <div id="header">

        <?php require_once('menu.php'); ?>
        <?php echo $logo; ?>
        <?php echo $menu; ?>

    </div>
   </div> 


<div id="main-container">   
<!-- List of logos -->
  <div id="logolist">
```

Comment: please post your html code as I can't know where you put the #mainpage .

Comment: You mean **left aligned** right?

Comment: have you added `html, body {height:100%}`?

Comment: @Pinocchio yes. it is left aligned. sorry. It was coming right aligned earlier. refresh causes left aligned :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is I use `fixed` positioning.

```
#mainpage
{

   position:fixed;
   width:840px;
   height:300px;
   top:50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -150px 0 0 -420px; /* [-(height/2)px 0 0 -(width/2)px] */
   background-color:#F1F1F1;

}
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvdnm/4/). Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using `top`, use `margin-top` and keep the position as `relative`

http://jsfiddle.net/xvdnm/

Check the JS Fiddle

`Top` has a different behaviour

> "top" is for tweak an element with use of "position" property. margin-top is for measuring the external distance to the element, in relation to the previous one.
>   Also, top behavior can differ depending on the type of position, absolute, relative or fixed.

*From:* [CSS: Top vs Margin-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top)

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Will it be at middle of the screen in devices like notepad , small screen monitors ?

Comment: Since you are using percentages, yes it will be. Or at least, it will try to fit it in the middle of the screen as long as the screen is big enough.

Comment: Do accept the answer that was most helpful to you, this will encourage people to keep answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are 'saying' to `#mainpage` to be 70% of the height of its parent (the `body`). However the `body` stretches with its content.

To fix your problem, you should set a height to the `body` and `html`:

```
html, body {
     height: 100%
}
```

Also check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/XsZjL/).