# Usage of top and negative margin-top in css

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain me the usage of `top, left and margin-left and margin-top` in the below code? I see we have given top a value and also margin-top a `negative` value. What does this actually achieve?.

```
#volume {
    width: 250px;
    height: 13px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #dddddd;
    top: 80%;
    left: 35%;
    margin-left: -125px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px #dddddd;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rbliK

Comment: There seems to be no practical reason to combine them in that example.

Comment: top is about positioning, margin-top specifies the margin around the element ( and padding is about the padding inside the element.

Comment: in this example, both do the same thing

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top

Comment: In fact combining `top` and `margin-top` can help you have a workaround for supporting a similar functionality with `calc()`, in this case it's similar to use `top: calc(80% - 15px)`. However maybe the code writer did not want to use `calc` method here because of its support. Also it's not a fully equivalent of using `calc`.

Comment: @KingKing: can the same effect be archived without the usage of top and margin-top?

Comment: as I said you can use `calc` function here, it should be what the writer meant (he might want to position the element exactly by `80%` but with an exact negative offset of `-15px`). With that requirement, normally we would use `calc` function, however ***IE8*** does not support it, also **IE** (even  ver 11) does not support animation with `calc` so using negative margin may be a work-around.

Comment: there is not any effect here, it's just a problem of ***positioning***  the element exactly by an offset of `-15px`. That's all. So if you don't want to position it that way, you can freely use just the `top`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin describes the space between your box and adjacent boxes. Setting a negative top margin indicates that you want negative spacing above your block. In simple words, margin to control the spacing between neighboring boxes and positive `top-margin` pushes content down, a negative `top-margin` pulls content up.

`top` and `left` on the other hand are `positional` attributes that specify where your box is located. The `top` `left` `bottom` `right` attributes specify the location of the respective edge of your box including its margin.

if you wanted the element to have no effect on the surrounding elements, you'd use `top` `left` `bottom` `right`

Check here for more info:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038375/3739658)