# Content after relative placed div

Tags: html, css

If I display a div relatively and give it a top margin, do I have to give all the following content the same top margin as well? Because the content that follows will be after the element's regular position.

http://jsfiddle.net/u9cgu6er/

As you can see here, the `blue` div is over the `red` one, which just follows blue's original position.

Is there a way to make `red` 20px lower without making it `relative`, as well? In other words, not do that with all the following content.

```css
#a {
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  height:50px;
}
#b {
  position:relative;
  top:20px;
  width:50%;
  background-color:blue;
  height:50px;
}
#c {
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: Why not to use `margin-top` rather than positioning the element?

Comment: Indeed. "top" isn't a margin -- it moves the element relative to the top of its natural position in the flow. Other elements outside of it will not be aware of its repositioning, but if you just used margins, that would work fine.

Comment: Also, you may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `margin-top: 20px;` to your `#c`. @HashemQolami is right, it will be easier to maintain your css by using `margin-top` on #b instead of position `relative` if you can.

Comment: Actually I meant using `margin-top` for `#b` rather than `top` offset. This is Hashem BTW :)

Comment: @HashemQolami, sorry for the mistake with your name!! I have corrected this, I'm really sorry!!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing would be to just set the `margin-top` of `#b` to 20px, and then `#c` will follow it.

```css
#a {
  width:100%;
  background-color:yellow;
  height:50px;
}
#b {
  margin-top:20px;
  width:50%;
  background-color:blue;
  height:50px;
}
#c {
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

This way, it doesn't remove `#b` from the document flow.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `margin-bottom: 40px;` to `#b` element:

```css
#a {
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:50px;
}
#b {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#c {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

or `margin-top: 40px;` to `#c` element:

```css
#a {
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:50px;
}
#b {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:50px;
    
}
#c {
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Either will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add margin 40px to the top of #c