# CSS - fixed navbar causing problems on window resize

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a **`navbar`** that always stays at the top, which I did, but I am having problems with the content on the page that goes under it and you can't see it.  I found that to fix this, I needed a 5% margin from the top of the body, but whenever I resize the width of the page, it affects the **`margin-top`**.  How would I get it so that the margin-top stays the same when resizing the width of the page?  An example of what I want is the **Instagram navbar** (website), like how the photos don't go overlapping the fixed **`navbar`** and on page resize it remains the same top margin.

**HTML**

```
<div>
     <div className="menu">
         <div className="left">
            <h1>PostNote</h1>
         </div>
         <div className="right">
            <span className="menu-item"><Link to="/">Home</Link></span>
            <span className="menu-item"><Link to="/searchNotes">Notes</Link></span>
            <span className="menu-item"><Link to="/addNote">Add a Note</Link></span>
            <span className="menu-item"><Link to={`/users/${Meteor.userId()}`} >My Profile</Link></span>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  margin-top:5%;
}
.menu{
  background: #F1F1F1;
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  position: fixed;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.menu-item{
  margin:5px;
  font-size:1.4em;
  color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some properties, the percentage unit will always use the percentage of the width. Margin is one of these properties, so when you are setting `margin-top: 5%;` it is using 5% of the body's width.

Instead, you could use `vh`. This unit is a % of the viewport's height. Therefore 1vh = 1% of the viewport height.

See 'Viewport-percentage lengths' [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706180/how-is-the-margin-top-percentage-calculated).

```
body{
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  margin-top:5vh;
}
```