# CSS Expand / Contract Animation to Show/Hide Content

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a box that can expand and collapse with a simple slide out animation.  If you run the example below, the idea is that it starts with one red line and when you click the button it separates into two read lines and gently expands to reveal the content like pulling a draw out of a table.

I've tried both transform, animation, relative: positioning with top, and i'm unable to get the desired effect.

The containing box should expand in size

```js
function expandContract() {
   const el = document.getElementById("expand-contract")
   el.classList.toggle('expanded')
   el.classList.toggle('collapsed')
}
```

```css
#container {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 15px;
}

#top-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#expand-contract {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.expand-contract {
   transform: translateY(-100%)
   overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%)
    }
}

.expanded {
   background-color: green;
   animation-name: slide-in;
   animation-duration: 1s;
}

.collapsed {
   background-color: red;
   transform: translateY(-100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top-section">
    This is always displayed
  </div>
  
  <div id="expand-contract" class="expanded">
    This section expands and contracts
  
    <table>
      <tr><td>test1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>test2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>test3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>test4</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <div id="bottom-section">
    This section is always displayed
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="expandContract()">Expand/Contract</button>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can achieve this using the CSS `transition` along with toggled styles. Initially you may think to transition the height (from `0` to `initial` so that it expands dynamically based on height) but unfortunately CSS `transition` doesn't properly handle this.

Instead, you can wrap it in a container of its own with `overflow: hidden` and then use a `margin-top: -100%` to hide it, and `0` to show it.

Here is your code with this modification:

```js
function expandContract() {
   const el = document.getElementById("expand-contract")
   el.classList.toggle('expanded')
   el.classList.toggle('collapsed')
}
```

```css
#container {
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 15px;
}

#top-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#expand-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#expand-contract {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: -100%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#expand-contract.expanded {
   background-color: green;
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top-section">
    This is always displayed
  </div>
  
  <div id="expand-container">
    <div id="expand-contract" class="expanded">
      This section expands and contracts
  
      <table>
        <tr><td>test1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>test2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>test3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>test4</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="bottom-section">
    This section is always displayed
  </div>
</div>

<button onclick="expandContract()">Expand/Contract</button>
```

Comment: When I contract the box and then click expand, there's a 1000ms delay before it expands.. any idea what would cause that?

Comment: transition: all 1s >> adds a 1 second delay.. changed this to transition: 1s all 0s;  to fix

Comment: Using `margin-top: -100%;` means the `-100%` will be computed w.r.t. the **width** of the containing box (in this case, `#expand-container`) - so this technique only works acceptably if the element to show or hide is shorter than the parent element is wide. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706180/how-is-the-margin-top-percentage-calculated

Comment: @TonyJWatson your solution causes the transition to not work at all

Comment: @TonyJWatson the delay is caused by the initial `margin-top` being -100% of the container's width, so it takes time for the animation to get visible.

Your fix sets the animation duration to 0 which effectively disables it.

Comment: As @Dai suggested, this answer has some issues and the animation is a bit quirky and would only work well with a square div (the actual animation won't be 1s either, depending on the content height). I suggest checking out this blog for some options (personally I prefer the 3rd, which unfortunately involves javascript and layout thrashing) https://carlanderson.xyz/how-to-animate-on-height-auto/

Answer (score 4):

here is an example that uses jquery

hope to help you

```js
function expandContract() {
    $header = $(".header");
    $content = $("#expand-contract")
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $header.text(function () {
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });
};
```

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .expanded {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="top-section">
      This is always displayed
    </div>
   <div id="expand-container">
    <div class="expanded" id="expand-contract">
         <table>
            <tr><td>test1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>test4</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="header" onclick="expandContract()">Expand/Contract</button>
```

also see codepen [here](https://codepen.io/thamtucity/pen/qppOYa).

Comment: "hoping to help" is good, but if you really want to help, include an educational explanation with every answer that you post.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround **without JS** just **CSS & HTML tricks**, making use of `<input type="checkbox" />` in order to
collapse/expand your content.

Below the snipped illustrates a dismissible alert.
The important thing here is that the `.wrapper` needs to have `overflow: hidden` and we play with `.alert`'s `height`.

If the `.alert` has `padding` we need to add a negative margin to the `.alert` when it's checked so that it behaves like it has been removed from context.

The collapse can either be triggered from the X button inside the `.alert` or from the Toggle button below.

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.alert {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
  transition: visibility .3s linear, opacity .3s ease, margin-top .3s ease, height .3s ease;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FEECCA;
}

.body {
    flex: 1;
}

.check {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
    
.check:checked + .alert {
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -40px; /* if your collapsible element has padding, use the top & bottom padding value */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
}
    
.button {
  padding:15px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" id="check1">
  <div class="alert">
    <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse nulla elit, iaculis vitae facilisis quis, sollicitudin elementum lacus. Nunc vitae tellus vel mi ullamcorper luctus. Nunc laoreet ligula diam.</div>
    <label class="close" for="check1" tabindex="0" aria-label="Close">
      <svg class="icon-close" width="12" height="12" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <path d="M2.897 0.434l28.303 28.303c0.579 0.579 0.579 1.518 0 2.096s-1.518 0.579-2.096 0l-28.303-28.303c-0.579-0.579-0.579-1.518 0-2.096s1.518-0.579 2.096 0z"></path>
        <path d="M0.8 29.469l28.303-28.303c0.579-0.579 1.518-0.579 2.096 0s0.579 1.518 0 2.096l-28.303 28.303c-0.579 0.579-1.518 0.579-2.096 0s-0.579-1.518 0-2.096z"></path>
      </svg>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<label class="button" for="check1" tabindex="0" aria-label="Toggle" role="button">Toggle Collapse/Expand</label>
```