# Margin-top percentage not relative to parent

Tags: html, css

I an having trouble understanding why the "square" class isn't relative to the parent, "container".

i.e - I set the container to have a height of 200px;
the "square" class is inside the container, and is floated left.

When I set margin-top to be 5%, it is not the 5% of 200px but something else. Why?

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.square {
  width: 20%;
  height: 70%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 5%; /* this guy right here */
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706180/how-is-the-margin-top-percentage-calculated) answer your question? Margins in percent are relative to the width of the container, not the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical padding and margin are relative to the width of the parent. Top and bottom on the other hand are not.

Try to place a div inside another. Use the top property (for example: top: 25%) and make sure you specify a position (e.g. position: relative;)

I've forked and adjusted your code example to demonstrate what I mean: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yaqmva

```
top: 5%;
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` property takes the width of the parent not the height. You could use some JavaScript to create height related margins.