# Is there any difference between 'margin-top, -left, -bottom, -right' and 'top, left, bottom, right' properties when element is positioned absolutely?

Tags: css

I am wondering if there is any difference between margins and positioning properties when I use `position: absolute` property on an element.

I know that there is huge difference when an element is positioned relatively, but when an element is out of hierarchy when it is absolutely positioned, there seems to be no difference.

I tried to create several elements, divs, paragraphs, headers and position them relatively and absolutely. Then I added margins and 'top, bottom, etc.' properties.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #363636;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>* {
/*   margin-top: 20px; */
}

.header {
  color: cyan;
  
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
/*   top: 20px; */
}

.title {
  color: red;
  
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.lorem {
  
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
  <h2 class="title">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
  <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente ab, cum, doloremque ratione quas officia placeat adipisci saepe hic similique perferendis voluptates molestiae ea id eius atque ipsum assumenda. Reprehenderit ullam nobis quis mollitia ab, nam eveniet ipsum in. Impedit ipsum odit quae facere! Voluptate illum, temporibus quasi natus repudiandae atque cupiditate laboriosam aliquam nostrum doloribus iste quibusdam commodi harum, earum ea doloremque! Eum temporibus commodi eaque aliquid ullam quod eius, praesentium dolores dicta! Aut eligendi repudiandae qui doloremque, id odit, nulla commodi quod quia molestiae blanditiis cum exercitationem atque eum maiores dolore quas rerum, laborum doloribus? Necessitatibus, facilis inventore.
  </p>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="info">E-mail address</p>
    <p class="location">America</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my codepen and element I am talking about is h1.header. When I am altering `margin-top: 20px` and `top: 20px` it seems identical.

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: Does this help and should I mark as duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top

Comment: @HassanVoyeau *Why are you asking?* --> because it's the purpose of this website : to ask questions

Comment: Put differently, what are you trying to achieve? Most answers will say it is not the same and give examples BUT how will you know all the differences without exact documentation, right? So if we know reason for asking then we address that without being able to point to all the differences documented somewhere.

Comment: @HassanVoyeau we don't always need to achieve something. Saying it's not the same by giving at least one example would be enough to demontrate that they are not the same and you answer the question since the OP think there is no difference. Adding references to show why and where it's documented would be optimal. Still without the need of having something to achieve in particular

Comment: So you don't have anything to achieve by knowing the answer? Weird.

Comment: I just want to know CSS better, that's it :)

Comment: @HassanVoyeau note that I am not the asker and for me the question is clear as stated. I don't need to know if there is something to be achieved with to answer it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif No worries, trying to give the best answer I could give but I needed some clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a difference related to the *static position*. Here is a simple example to illustrate:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>I am static</h1>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h1>I am static</h1>
  <div style="position:absolute;margin-top:20px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h1>I am static</h1>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:20px;"></div>
</div>
```

Note how in the first example, the element is shifted by `20px` from its initial position (that we call *static position*) whereas in the second example it's shifted by `20px` from the top of the parent element (containing block).

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> For the purposes of this section and the next, the term "static position" (of an element) refers, roughly, **to the position an element would have had in the normal flow**. More precisely, the static position for 'top' is the distance from the top edge of the containing block to the top margin edge of a hypothetical box that would have been the first box of the element if its specified 'position' value had been 'static' and its specified 'float' had been 'none' and its specified 'clear' had been 'none'...

Then we have:

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> `'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block`

Then the first case will follow this:

> If all three of 'top', 'height', and 'bottom' are auto, set 'top' **to the static position** and apply rule number three below.

And the second one will follow this:

> 'bottom' is 'auto', 'top' and 'height' are not 'auto', then set 'auto' values for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' to 0 and solve for 'bottom'

Both will behave the same if the *static position* is the same when setting `top:0`. Basically, when the element is the first one in its containing block

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.box>div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <h1>I am static</h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div style="position:absolute;margin-top:20px;"></div>
  <h1>I am static</h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div style="position:absolute;top:20px;"></div>
  <h1>I am static</h1>
</div>
```

Worth to note that you can combine both of them. You simply need to apply the correct rule as stated in the specification.

---

Same logic apply to `margin-left/right` and `left/right`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and such a detailed answer, now I understand!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, especially when the absolutely positioned item isn't the first item in it's anchor.  You will notice the only thing I changed was that I added a `<p>Some text</p>` in there, and now margin-top and top don't act so similarly before.

There is likely other rules that play differently as well. There are cases in which margins collapse.  top never "collapses".

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #363636;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper>* {
/*   margin-top: 20px; */
}

.header {
  color: cyan;
  
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px;
/*   top: 20px; */
}

.title {
  color: red;
  
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.lorem {
  
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text</p>
  <h1 class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
  <h2 class="title">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h2>
  <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente ab, cum, doloremque ratione quas officia placeat adipisci saepe hic similique perferendis voluptates molestiae ea id eius atque ipsum assumenda. Reprehenderit ullam nobis quis mollitia ab, nam eveniet ipsum in. Impedit ipsum odit quae facere! Voluptate illum, temporibus quasi natus repudiandae atque cupiditate laboriosam aliquam nostrum doloribus iste quibusdam commodi harum, earum ea doloremque! Eum temporibus commodi eaque aliquid ullam quod eius, praesentium dolores dicta! Aut eligendi repudiandae qui doloremque, id odit, nulla commodi quod quia molestiae blanditiis cum exercitationem atque eum maiores dolore quas rerum, laborum doloribus? Necessitatibus, facilis inventore.
  </p>
  <div class="footer">
    <p class="info">E-mail address</p>
    <p class="location">America</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you , I think I understand the difference, `margin-top` refers to the element before this header, and `top`  to parent element, right?

Comment: Not really.  What margin was meant to do, and what it is used to do is often different, but... margin: 20px basically says keep everything at least 20px away from my edges.  top on the other hand has different meaning depending on the element's position attribute.  If it is position:relative, then top:20px says to move the element down 20px from where it would have been if it was position:static.  If the element is position:absolute, then it says to move it down 20px from the top of it's anchoring element.

Comment: To find the anchoring element for something position:absolute, start crawling up the element's ancestors (It's parent/container, then that element's parent/container, then that element's parent/container, etc.) until you find the first one that is not position:static.  In your case, the parent of .header is the .wrapper element, and that element is position:relative, so that is the anchor.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, so `margin-top` is keeping everything away and since it is posiotioned absolutely it is moving away from an element before, while `top` is moving element in relation to first ancestor element positioned differently than `static`.

Comment: Close enough, yes.