# Unable to overwrite css top property in prime react menu component

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules, primereact

I'm trying to get rid of the space as shown in the image below:

[image]

I'm using the Menu component of primereact from [this documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/menu)

Here's my constructor code for reference:

```
constructor() {
        super();
            this.state = {
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'First Services',
                        items: [
                        {label: 'firstitem', 
                        command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl','_blank');}},

                        {label: 'firstitemname', 
                        command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl#get-firstitemname','_blank');}},


                        {label: 'firstcategoryname', 
                        command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl#get-firstcategoryname','_blank');}},



                            ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: 'Second Services',
                        items: [
                        {label: 'testforuser ',
                        command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl#get-testforuser','_blank');}},

                        {label: 'testforproject', 
                        command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl#get-testforproject','_blank');}},


                        {label: 'testforprotocol ',
                        command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl#get-testforprotocol','_blank');}}




                    ]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Workflows ',
                        items: [
                        {label: 'Workflow for User ',
                         command: (event) => {window.open('http://someurl#workflow-section','_blank');}}
                    ]
                    }, 
                ]
            };
     }
```

And here's my `Menu` and `Button` component defined:

```
                      <Menu 
                        model={this.state.items} 
                        popup={true} 
                        style={{fontSize:'16px'},{width:'12%'}}
                        ref={el => this.menu = el}
                        />
                         <Button  
                        label="My DropDown Menu" 
                        icon="pi pi-bars"
                        style={{width:'12%'},{backgroundColor:'#000000'}}

                         onClick={

                            (event)=>this.menu.toggle(event)
                        }
                        />
```

I figured out the reason why there's space between the `Button` and the `Menu`. When I right clicked on the `MY DROPDOWN MENU` and selected `Inspect Element Q` on my Firefox browser, I saw the following-the css `top` property is set to `118.5px`. :

[image]

I'm trying to overwrite the `top` property and change it to `60px` from `118.5px`. For that I tried modifying my code like this:

```
                   <Menu 
                    model={this.state.items} 
                    popup={true} 
                    style={{fontSize:'16px'},{width:'12%'},{marginTop:'60px'}}
                    ref={el => this.menu = el}
                    />
```

But it ended up showing as a separate property like this:

[image]

How can I modify `top` property?

Answer (score 0):

Top and margin-top are 2 different things in CSS.

```
style={{
    top:'60px'
}}
```

[CSS: Top vs Margin-top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036176/css-top-vs-margin-top)

Comment: So how should i modify `top` value in my example? Can you answer my question?

Comment: yes just like the code I gave, ADD  top:'60px'   no place for margin there (margin is another thing you don't need there), give feedback if it worked :)
WITH FEW WORDS: replace 'marginTop' with 'top' and magic

Comment: Thanks. It showed up there for the first time and when I started playing around (by playing around I mean when I clicked the drop down menu and then right clicked on Inspect element Q couple of times)with it, it again changed to 118.5px and another time it changed to -243.5px and same problem still persists :(

Answer (score 0):

First check what classes are being used by the `primereact` menu, using console, then make a `.css` file and import into your `.js` file. Write the same name of the class as you found out using console and then override the properties you want. Then run your app again. It should work. P.S. I tried this before and this worked for me.